# What do these horizontal lines represent in the PhpStorm IDE?

Tags: php, phpstorm

They do not appear when I put the condition inside the `try {}`

[image]

Comment: This is an english speaking platform. Please provide your question in english. Tnanks

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I already edited the question.

Comment: Hover over that little lightbulb

Comment: Handling unhandled exceptions "unhandled\Exceptions..."

Comment: I think the colours themselves are set at "File / Settings / Editor / Color Scheme / General / Errors and Warnings".

Comment: You have a Warning there (some inspection returned an alert for that part of the code with Warning severity). You can change the styling (color/underline effect etc) by editing your Color Scheme (just as Álvaro González suggested).

Answer (score 0):

Phpstorm highlights those lines because one or more of the functions being called throws an Exception. There's three ways to go around this issue.

#### Add a `try` / `catch` block

you can surround the highlighted code with a `try`/ `catch` block, and then do something with the Exception (ex: logging the message to the console).

```
public function get() {
    try {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

#### Add a phpdoc comment to the function

If you wish to let the potential Exception bubble up, you can simply add a phpdoc comment to your function. Be aware though, that unless you list every potential Exception, or the generic Exception type, Phpstorm will then warn you about missing `@throws` statement.

```
/**
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function get() {
    throw new Exception();
}
```

#### disable or alter the IDE settings

The "Unhandled Exception" warning in Phpstorm is considered to be a warning, and not a syntax highlight. As such, you can either enable or disable it, or adjust its severity level. You can find the related setting in `Settings` > `Editor` > `Inspections` and then selecting `PHP` > `Error handling` > `Unhandled expection`

I would advise against disabling the highlight, knowing when and where an Exception might thrown can help in preventing bugs and making the codebase generally more stable.

---

Note that you *can* change the actual style of the warning, but doing so will affect any other warning of the same severity level. To do so, go in `Settings` > `Editor` > `Color scheme` > `General` > `Errors and Warnings` and select the warning level that applies (`Warning` by default)

Comment: Thank you. I did exactly as you said and it worked. I put the code inside a try try / catch